# ActiveRecord/Rails: most efficient way to count results of multiple queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm new to ActiveRecord. I'm trying to optimize a database query.

I've got a `Person` model with `gender` column. A person's `gender` can have one of three values: `male`, `female`, or `transgendered`.  I want to know the number of people of each gender.

I'm currently doing this with three separate database queries.

```
numMale = Person.where(:gender => :male).count
numFemale = Person.where(:gender => :female).count
numTrans = Person.where(:gender => :transgendered).count
```

Could these be made more efficient? Is there a way to combine them into a single database call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a group by query to aggregate all the data:

```
Person.all(:group => "gender", :select => "gender, COUNT(*) as count")
```

Then you can split out the values and assign to your variables.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#count`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count). The syntax depends on your Rails on Rails version.

```
# Rails 3.2
Person.count(:group => :gender)

# Rails 4+
Person.group(:gender).count
```

`count` returns a Hash like `{ 'male' => 12, 'female' ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
Person.select('gender,count(*)').where(:gender => [:male,:female,:transgendered]).group(:gender)
```

would return

```
SELECT gender,count(*) FROM `people`  WHERE `people`.`gender` IN ('male', 'female', 'transgendered') GROUP BY gender
```

Comment: I don't think you the `group by` the count should do

Comment: is some RDBMS such as Oracle, count does not work without group by

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
`Person.where(gender: [:male, :female, :transgendered]).count`